# Integrated graphics output when dedicated gpu is broken

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu, external-display

I have a laptop with integrated and dedicated graphics, but the dedicated graphics recently broke. The laptop still runs fine (albeit with a worse graphics card), but it doesn't seem to output to another display. I've tried updating drivers and such already with no success. I also reinstalled windows after the dedicated graphics broke, so the system only knows about the igpu. My best guess is that the output ports are hardwired to the broken gpu, but I haven't found a way to confirm that. That also seems unlikely, because I would think that at least one would be able to run from the igpu in cases like this? Any help/ideas would be appreciated <3

Laptop model: MSI GE76 Raider 10UE

Comment: Try running the second one via USB.  You might be able to use the video ram from the broken gpu that way.  It's cheap to find out.

Comment: Are you talking about the integrated or dedicated one? I can look at getting an adapter, but I'm concerned about latency

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  It will indeed have latency but USB 3.x seems to be fairly zippy in my setup.  Fine for programming.. gaming will probably not give you the frame rates you want.

Comment: Oh.. and I believe that those adapters are living off of the same memory pool.  @Ramhound would know should he choose to chime in.

Comment: You're correct with your best guess, that's exactly what almost everyone building laptops with hybrid graphics does, as a cost saving exercise, and because the not entirely incorrect assumption that if you're using external monitors then you're near an electric outlet so the (battery) energy saving is moot.

Comment: Sounds good, I will look at getting an adapter. Thanks for the help!